Firebase: Issue with Firebase Crashlytics and Messaging Service
I'm encountering a peculiar issue with Firebase Crashlytics and Firebase Messaging service in my Android project. I've made sure of the following:

The project includes the google-services.json file.
I'm using the following Firebase dependencies:
gradle


implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.6.3"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.4.1"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.0.0"
classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9"



I have debugged the logs for forebase crashlytics. Here are they:

04-04 17:16:38.830 31334 31359 W FirebaseCrashlytics: Crashlytics
report could not be enqueued to DataTransport 04-04 17:16:38.830 31334
31359 W FirebaseCrashlytics: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
Transport backend 'cct' is not registered 04-04 17:16:38.830 31334
31359 W FirebaseCrashlytics:   at
com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.DefaultScheduler.lambda$schedule$1$com-google-android-datatransport-runtime-scheduling-DefaultScheduler(DefaultScheduler.java:77)



For Firebase Crashlytics, I debugged the app and found the following logs. I've tried solutions from various GitHub issues, but none seem to work for me.
Regarding Firebase Messaging, I'm facing difficulties with debugging. I'm unable to generate the token unless I add the following lines to my AndroidManifest.xml:

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingRegistrar"
    android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsRegistrar"
    android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.crashlytics.CrashlyticsRegistrar"
    android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />


However, after adding these lines, I'm unable to receive notifications.
I would greatly appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve these issues. Thank you!
